# Why my blender always crash while running script?

Tags: scripting

Open blender and run script after 3-5 times later, it will crash and no response, even only a few lines of code.
[image]

Each time I have to close and restart it, how to solve this problem?
This is one part of my script.

```
from ast import Global
import collections
from operator import iadd
from pickle import TRUE
import re
import bpy
import math
import random
from mathutils import Vector
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import shapely.geometry


import numpy as np

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data



def orient_vector(object):
    # center = object.location
    orient_vec = object.matrix_world @ (Vector((1, 0, 0, 0)))

    return orient_vec[0:3]


def ret_obb(verts):
    """
    Description:
    Get verts of object and calculate object's OBB

    Return:

    """
    points = np.asarray(verts)
    means = np.mean(points, axis=1)

    cov = np.cov(points, y = None,rowvar = 0,bias = 1)

    v, vect = np.linalg.eig(cov)

    tvect = np.transpose(vect)
    points_r = np.dot(points, np.linalg.inv(tvect))

    co_min = np.min(points_r, axis=0)
    co_max = np.max(points_r, axis=0)

    xmin, xmax = co_min[0], co_max[0]
    ymin, ymax = co_min[1], co_max[1]
    zmin, zmax = co_min[2], co_max[2]

    xdif = (xmax - xmin) * 0.5
    ydif = (ymax - ymin) * 0.5
    zdif = (zmax - zmin) * 0.5

    cx = xmin + xdif
    cy = ymin + ydif
    cz = zmin + zdif

    corners = np.array([
        [cx - xdif, cy - ydif, cz - zdif],
        [cx - xdif, cy + ydif, cz - zdif],
        [cx + xdif, cy + ydif, cz - zdif],
        [cx + xdif, cy - ydif, cz - zdif],
        [cx - xdif, cy - ydif, cz + zdif],
        [cx - xdif, cy + ydif, cz + zdif],
        [cx + xdif, cy + ydif, cz + zdif],
        [cx + xdif, cy - ydif, cz + zdif],
    ])

    corners = np.dot(corners, tvect)

    return [Vector((el[0], el[1], el[2])) for el in corners]


def Align():
    '''
    Description:
    choose all objects in nected collection then aline to one direction

    '''
    
    def ViewRectangle(obj):
            """
            Description:
            Define object's visible area, after align()

            """
            if Viewable(obj):
                temp = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(obj["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull
                # x_i = (a, b)

                x_0 = temp.exterior.coords[0]
                x_1 = temp.exterior.coords[1]
                x_2 = temp.exterior.coords[2]
                x_3 = temp.exterior.coords[3]
                
                obj.select_get()
                point_0 = x_3
                point_1 = x_2
                point_2 = (x_2[0] + 3, x_2[1])
                point_3 = (x_3[0] + 3, x_3[1])

                bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
                bpy.context.object.scale[0] = 3
                bpy.context.object.scale[1] = x_1[1] - x_0[1]
                bpy.context.object.location[0] = (x_0[0] + (x_2[0] - x_1[0])/2) + (x_2[0] - x_1[0])/2 + 1.5
                bpy.context.object.location[1] = x_0[1] + (x_1[1] - x_0[1])/2
                bpy.context.object.name = obj.name + '_' + 'viewRec'

                bpy.data.objects[bpy.context.object.name].select_set(True)


    for object in bpy.data.collections["furniture"].all_objects:
        name = object.name

        object.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.transform.transform(mode='ALIGN', value=(0, 0, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
        object.location.z = 0
        accessableArea(object)
        
        # rechoose object
        object.select_set(True)
        ViewRectangle(object)
        # bpy.data.objects["Cube"].select_set(True)
        bpy.data.objects[name].select_set(True)

        # combine object and its view rectangle into one 
        bpy.ops.object.join()
        object.select_set(False)




def Viewable(object):
    """
    Description:
    Check if object is visible object.

    Return: True or False
    """
    
    object_front_name = object.name.split("_")[0]
    object_last_name = object.name.split("_")[1]
    
    if object_last_name == 'TV' or object_front_name == 'cupboard':
        return True
    else:
        return False


def Visible_cost(group):
    """
    Description: If some object in one object's visible area, then cost will rise. 
    Here we define cost as the area of intersection of one object with another object's visible area
    """

    # group: bpy.data.collections["x"]
    for obj in group.all_objects:
        if Viewable(obj):
            name = obj.name + '_' + 'viewRec'
            bpy.data.objects[name].select_set(True)
            verts = [v.co[:] for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices]
            plane_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(verts).convex_hull
            for obj_other in group.all_objects:
                if obj_other != obj:
                    obj_other.select_set(True)
                    verts_o = [v.co[:] for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices]
                    x = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(verts_o).convex_hull
                    if x.intersects(plane_poly):
                        return x.intersection(plane_poly).area
                    else:
                        return 0

    

def touchable(object):
    """
    Description:
    define if an object touchable

    Return:True or False
    """
    if object.name.split("_")[0] == 'sofa' or 'table' or 'chair':
        return True
    
    elif object.name.split("_")[0] == 'potting' or 'water_cooler' or 'cupboard':
        return False

def accessableArea(object):
    '''
    Description:
    One property for object.

    Return: object's acessable area(4 points)

    '''
    if object.name != 'door' or 'Plane' or 'window':
        object.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
        verts = [v.co for v in object.data.vertices]
        obb_local = ret_obb(verts)
        mat = object.matrix_world
        obb_world = [mat @ v for v in obb_local]

        # Visualization
        # bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

        # # draw with GPU Module
        # coords = [(v[0], v[1], v[2]) for v in obb_world]

        # indices = (
        #     (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0),
        #     (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 4),
        #     (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7))

        # shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
        # batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": coords}, indices=indices)


        # def draw():
        #     shader.bind()
        #     shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 0, 0, 1))
        #     batch.draw(shader)

        # bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

        # EXAMPLE of object's bottom_poly: [(x_1, x_2), (x_3, x_4), ... , (x_k, x_k+1)]
        list = []
        for x in range(len(obb_world)):
            if abs(obb_world[x][:][2]) <= 1:
                list.append(obb_world[x][:][0:2])
        
        object["bottom_poly"] = list
        object["accessArea"] = shapely.affinity.scale(shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(object["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull, xfact = 1.2, yfact = 1.2).exterior.coords[:]

        object.select_set(False)

    # box = object.bound_box
    # p = [object.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in box]




    

def CheckIfHit(object_1, object_2):
    """
    Description:
    check if object_1's bottom hit to object_2's bottom

    Return:
    True or False
    """
    
    obj_1_bottom_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(object_1["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull
    obj_2_bottom_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(object_2["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull

    return obj_1_bottom_poly.intersects(obj_2_bottom_poly)

def CheckIntersect(object_1, object_2):
    """
    Description:
    check if object_1's bottom in object_2's accessible area and return intersected point list

    Return:
    list of object_1's bottom points which intersected with object_2's access area
    """

    temp = object_2["accessArea"]
    obj_2_access_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(temp).convex_hull

    intersectPoint = []

    for i in object_1["bottom_poly"]:
        i = shapely.geometry.Point(list(i))
        if obj_2_access_poly.intersects(i):
            intersectPoint.append(i)
        
    if not list:
        return False
    elif list:
        return intersectPoint
    
def select_from_collection(some_collection):
    """ Recursively select objects from the specified collection """

    list = []
    for a_collection in some_collection.children:
        select_from_collection(a_collection)
    for obj in some_collection.objects:
        obj.select_set(True)
        list.append(obj)
        obj.select_set(False)

    return list

def calc1(list, object_2):
    """
    Description:
    Calculate the cost when A in B's access area but not hit with B

    list: list of points in access area

    object_2: object where A's points in its access area

    Return: 
    cost(double)
    """

    temp = object_2["bottom_poly"]
    # obj_2_poly_context = {'type': 'MULTIPOLYGON',
    # 'coordinates': [[[list(temp[0]), list(temp[1]), list(temp[2]), list(temp[3])]]]}

    # # to calculate the distance from point to object_2's edge, first we set up object_2's shape
    # obj_2_poly_shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(obj_2_poly_context)
    obj_2_bottom_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(temp).convex_hull

    center = obj_2_bottom_poly.centroid

    sum_cost = 0
    for i in list:
        i = shapely.geometry.Point(list(i))
        dis = center.distance(i)
        cost = math.exp(1/dis)
        sum_cost += cost

    return sum_cost

def calc2(list, object_1, object_2):
    """
    Description:
    Calculate the cost when A in B's access area and hit with B
    use intersect area + calc1(~) as cost

    """

    point_cost = calc1(list, object_2)

    obj_1_bottom_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(object_1["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull
    obj_2_bottom_poly = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(object_2["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull

    inter_area = obj_1_bottom_poly.intersection(obj_2_bottom_poly).area

    
    return point_cost + inter_area
    

def access_cost(group):
    """
    Description: if one object was set into an access area of another object, 
    this function calculate the cost for this sence

    Return: cost
    """

    list = select_from_collection(group)
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)-i):
            # if they are 2 different objects
            if i != i+j:
                # if A in B's access area:(A count is list[i], B count is list[i+j])
                if CheckIntersect(list[i], list[i+j]) != False:
                    # if A not hit or cover B
                    if CheckIfHit(list[i], list[i+j]) == False:
                        Intersect_point_list = CheckIntersect(list[i], list[i+j])
                        cost = calc1(Intersect_point_list, list[i+j])
                    # if A hit or cover B
                    else:
                        cost = calc2(Intersect_point_list, list[i], list[i+j])
                else:
                    continue
    
    return cost
        

def attract_cost(group):
    """
    Description:
    To solve simulated annealing process without wall limitation problem, define attraction cost function to avoid 
    objects scattered too much.

    Return: cost
    """

    max_lenth = 10# m, lenth of room
    def func(x):
        if x/max_lenth > 1:
            return math.exp(x/max_lenth - 1)
        else:
            return x/max_lenth

    list = select_from_collection(group)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)-i):
            if i != i+j:
                point_a = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(list[i]["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull.centroid
                point_b = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(list[i+j]["bottom_poly"]).convex_hull.centroid
                dis = point_a.distance(point_b)
                sum += dis
    average_dis = sum/len(list)
    return func(average_dis)

def total_cost(group):
    """
    Return attract cost, normal cost and visible cost.
    """
    # group: bpy.data.collections["x"]
    print(attract_cost(group))
    print(access_cost(group))
    print(Visible_cost(group))
    return attract_cost(group) + access_cost(group) + Visible_cost(group)

def move(object, T):
    """
    Description:move object randomly
    
    """

    std = math.sqrt(T/10)
    m = np.random.normal(0, std, 1)
    if np.random.randint(2):
        object.location.x += m
    else:
        object.location.y += m
    

def rotate(object, T, T_0):
    """
    Description:rotate object randomly
    """
    std = math.pi * (T/T_0)
    r = np.random.normal(0, std, 1)
    object.rotation_euler.z = r




def simulated_annealing(group):
    """
    """
    #         roomPoints= [geometry.Point(0,0),geometry.Point(100,0)
    #                      ,geometry.Point(100,100),geometry.Point(0,100)]

    # num: iteration times
    # alpha: cooling index
    # group: bpy.context.collection
    T_0 = 100
    T_F = 1
    num = 250
    count = 0
    alpha = 0.99
    T = T_0
    global beta
    beta = -1/T
    # initial arrangement
    c_0 = total_cost(group)

    T = T_0
    while T > T_F:
        for i in range(num):
            # generate new arrangement randomly
            for obj in group.objects:
                if np.random.randint(2):
                    move(obj)
                else:
                    rotate(obj)
            new_c = total_cost(group)


            if i == 0:
                old_c = c_0

            # if receive new solution:
            if Metropolis(old_c, new_c):
                old_c = new_c
                T = T * alpha
                count += 1
            

def Metropolis(old_c, new_c):
    """
    Description:
    1 means receive change

    0 means reject change

    """
    if new_c < old_c:
        
        return 1
    else:
        probability = math.exp(beta*(old_c - new_c))

        # recieve new solution probably
        if random() < probability:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Align()
    simulated_annealing(bpy.data.collections["group_TV"])
```

Blender version：3.0
python version：3.7

Comment: Please paste your script into your question

Comment: I don't think it relate to my code, because even a simply if and else it will crash too after running several times. My code is debugging, it is long and might ahave many mistakes. I'll paste it up if it could help.@MartyFouts

Comment: If that's the case then please edit your post to include the simplest version of a script that results in a crash. You may want to take a look at the the [Gotchas page of the Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#help-my-script-crashes-blender). However, based on your screenshot, it seems that Blender rather hangs/freezes than crashes/closes unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes it better be discribe as freezes instead of crash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this example will, as you might say, crash Blender:

```
while True:
    pass
```

But this is not an issue, because you've made an infinite loop, that makes Blender execute it without end. While Blender execute Python script, it doesn't update the interface. And if the script executed too long, Windows might suppose that Blender freezes.

Some scripts execute too long, but after several minutes they finish the work. In that case, Windows can show a dialog that the program does not response, but you may click "wait" so there is no issue here.